# Tax implementations in stock management type systems

Tags: c#, vb.net, standards

Is anyone aware of any “standard” or articles/books that cover the best way to implement tax details in stock management type system in a generic and worldwide compatible way?

Alternatively if you have specific suggestions or experience on the subject your input would be appreciated.

(Bonus points for .NET specific advise - although can't imagine the language changes the details much)

*To be more specific regarding what I mean by "tax details". What I am asking is how does one build a system that can "reasonably" well deal with the difference in tax laws between countries and states. I understand this is a vague question but I am not sure that it could be expressed better.*

*My first gut instinct was to just create a tax-rate field and assume that will suffice but now I am starting to wonder.*

Comment: "tax details" is one of the most uncommon thing across countries, I don't think there is "generic and worldwide compatible way"

Comment: I've used TaxWare in the past, but they seem to be mostly US-focused.  (And even that is a huge pain -- there's huge variation in tax laws between states, counties, and cities).  I can't imagine the variation between countries!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start here:  http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=international+taxation&x=0&y=0

Your question is pretty vague, and I certainly don't have any technical answers for you.  But, I would imagine that you need to create a general rules engine that is pluggable to just about every kind of business transaction and event that occurs in your system.